# Flurl: cannot serialize JSON string received from HttpTest

Tags: c#, flurl

I want to receive a JSON from my REST API and translate it to POCOs. It's supposed to be simple but it turns out to be not :(

In my unit test I have a string of sample JSON data that the API sends:

```
string mockJsonResponse = @"[{
                ""project_name"": ""Mailjet Support"",
                ""cluster_name"": ""24/7 Support"",
                ""is_billable"": ""1"",
                ""usedtime"": ""128""
            },
            {
                ""project_name"": ""Caring"",
                ""cluster_name"": ""Caring"",
                ""is_billable"": ""0"",
                ""usedtime"": ""320""
            },
            {
                ""project_name"": ""Engagement"",
                ""cluster_name"": ""Community"",
                ""is_billable"": ""0"",
                ""usedtime"": ""8""
            }]";
```

which I send to my code from the test through HttpTest:

```
httpTest.RespondWithJson(mockJsonResponse);
```

I am trying to receive it in my code:

```
dynamic response = "http://api.com".GetJsonListAsync();
```

But it always fails with a very generic error in the Test Explorer:

`Result Message:    Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException : Request to http://api.com failed.`

Further digging it seems like it cannot serialize the string into poco. I've tried doing manual serializing directly with the string variable above and it translates to my model class easily, so it could not have been a code structure problem.

```
// same string variable above
var jsons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(mockJsonResponse); // this runs fine
```

All of these failed:

```
dynamic response = await "http://www.api.com".GetJsonAsync();
dynamic response = await "http://www.api.com".GetJsonAsync<Model>();
var response = await "http://www.api.com".GetJsonAsync<Model>();    
IList<dynamic> response = await "http://www.api.com".GetJsonListAsync();
```

The model class:

```
public class Model
{
    public string project_name { get; set; }
    public string cluster_name { get; set; }
    public string is_billable { get; set; }
    public string usedtime { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**
I tried getting it as a string with `GetStringAsync`, and it seems like the string got mangled somehow. This string passed on to `JsonConvert.Deserialize<Model>()` will fail the test. This is what Visual Studio debugger shows. There's a lot of escape characters.

[image: Screenshot of the string received from HttpTest in Visual Studio debugger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RespondWithJson` takes an object that will be serialized to JSON for you, not a string that is already serialized. Represent the test response with an anonymous object and you should be good:

```
var mockJsonResponse = new[] {
    new {
        project_name = "Mailjet Support",
        cluster_name = "24/7 Support",
        is_billable = "1",
        usedtime = "128"
    },               
    new {                
        project_name = "Caring",
        cluster_name = "Caring",
        is_billable = "0",
        usedtime = "320"
    },             
    new {               
        project_name = "Engagement",
        cluster_name = "Community",
        is_billable = "0",
        usedtime = "8"
    }
};

httpTest.RespondWithJson(mockJsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

In trying to manually mock up the json you are not produsing well formatted JSON.

I would suggest creating a collection, serializing it and return that as your sample JSON.

```
Model[] models = new []{
    new Model {
        project_name = "Mailjet Support",
        cluster_name = "24/7 Support",
        is_billable = "1",
        usedtime = "128"
    },               
    new Model{                
        project_name = "Caring",
        cluster_name = "Caring",
        is_billable = "0",
        usedtime = "320"
    },             
    new Model{               
        project_name = "Engagement",
        cluster_name = "Community",
        is_billable = "0",
        usedtime = "8"
    }
};

string mockJsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(models);
```